# Help running World of Warcraft in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I'e been trying to play world of Warcraft on Ubuntu. I even tried on Mint. Tried Playonlinux, trial of crossover and just Wine 1.6.2 and Wine 1.7 can anyone give me some assistance. I'm new to linux

64 BIT Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score -1):

If you check on WineHQ and the WoW forums the 64 bit version is not working. You currently need to run 32-bit.

Comment: Are you talking about OS bits, or the application?